# Increasing difficulty of a Sprite Kit game

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, nstimer, skaction

I 've got a game made with Sprite Kit and it has a SKAction which performs a method and repeats it forever with a time interval:

```
 _action = [SKAction sequence:@[
                                          [SKAction waitForDuration:difficulty],
                                          [SKAction performSelector:@selector(addPlayer) onTarget:self]]];

    [self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:_action] withKey:playerKey];
```

But I want the time interval to decrease 0.01 seconds every second and for that I used a timer:

```
difficultyTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(decrease) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Which repeats this method:

```
- (void)decrease {
difficulty -= 0.01;
NSLog(@"Difficulty: %.2f", difficulty);
}
```

I tried setting `difficulty` as a float and as a NSTimeInterval but the timer doesn't affects the SKAction `-waitForDuration`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `update` function of the `SKScene` to add players with changing `waitDuration`. The `update` method is called every frame with the `currentTimeInterval` as parameter. We can use the calculate the time elapsed between the last `addPlayer` call and current frame. If it's greater than `difficulty` wait duration, then we will update it again.

First create a `property` like this

```
@property (nonatomic) NSTimeInterval lastAddPlayerTime;
```

Then in the `update` function

```
-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    if (currentTime - self.lastAddPlayerTime >= difficulty) {
        self.lastAddPlayerTime = currentTime;
        [self addPlayer];
    }
}
```

You can also create a repeating `SKAction` to decrease the `difficulty variable` every second.

```
SKAction *increaseDifficultyAction = [SKAction
                                      sequence:@[[SKAction waitForDuration:1.0],
                                                 [SKAction runBlock:^{
    difficulty -= 0.01;
}]]];

[self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:increaseDifficultyAction]];
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working perfectly but I want to make the `difficulty` variable start again when the game overs. I've tried this code but it doesn't work:
`SKAction *increaseDifficultyAction = [SKAction
                                      sequence:@[[SKAction waitForDuration:1.0],
                                                 [SKAction runBlock:^{
      if (gameover == NO) {
                    difficulty -= 0.01;
                }else {
                    difficulty = 1.0;
                }
}]]];

[self runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:increaseDifficultyAction]];`

Comment: `gameover`is a BOOL that checks if the game is over or not

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a time interval to the addPlayer action, you should create an update action which will call an update method every so often and then inside of that function have your logic for adding players.

For example, if you set up a timer to run every 0.1 seconds you can create a counter variable to see how many "updates" have gone by and then have a "difficulty" variable to determine after how many updates you want to add a player.

**PSUEDO CODE:**

```
-(void)update{
  counter+=1;
   if(counter%difficulty == 0)  
   {
    addPlayer();
   }
}
```

This way you can have all of your logic in one place and based off the same "update" schedule. You can add an enemy after 3 updates, change the background after 5 updates, etc.